# Implementing the Monad typeclass with a multi-parameter type

Tags: scala, syntax, scalaz

In scala, I have a container type with an error case and held type:

```
case class Extract[E, A](runView: View => EitherT[Future, E, (A, View)]) {...}
```

Which I intend to use as a sort of asynchronous state monad. I have implemented all of the `map`, `flatMap` utility methods for this.

I now want to mark this type as being a member of the Monad type class in scalaz, and I'm struggling to work out the syntax for specifying that the type parameter I want the type monadic over is the A type, since Monad takes a type with a single type parameter. Below is an incorrect attempt I made.

```
implicit def extractInterface[E] = new Monad[Extract[E, A]] {
    def point[A](a: => A): Extract[E, A] = {...}
    def bind[A, B](fa: Extract[E, A])(f: (A) => Extract[E, B]): Extract[E, B] = fa.flatMap(f)
}
```

I have tried looking at the scalaz instances for `E \/ A`, but they use a `?` type parameter, for which I cannot find a definition.

Is there a syntactic trick to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [type lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)

```
implicit def extractInterface[E] = new Monad[({ type λ[A] = Extract[E, A] })#λ] {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) plugin.

```
implicit def extractInterface[E] = new Monad[Extract[E, ?]] {
  ...
}
```

[What is the ? type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386103/what-is-the-type)